# Oracle spatial Polygons

Tags: oracle, polygon, oracle-spatial

I'm searching for an example/explanation how to save geographic references that describes polygons for Oracle Databases.

I've found out, that SDO_GEOMETRY seems to work for that case generally. How can I put multiple 'nodes' into SDO_GEOMETRY?

A little example would be great!

Comment: The [Oracle Spatial documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11830/toc.htm) would be a good place to start.

Comment: Thank you. I've already read a lot in there. Since I'm pretty new to Spatial Data I really had problems understanding the details.

Comment: Are you after insert statement from sql developer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example sql would be
select sdo_geometry(2003, null, null,
              mdsys.sdo_elem_info_array(1, 1003, 3),
              mdsys.sdo_ordinate_array(671   ,672, 849   ,850)) from dual

Best place to start is "Pro Oracle Spatial for Oracle Database 11g" http://www.apress.com/9781590598993.